# Joomla insert elements in articles with component

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-component

I need to insert a URL/button in every article but I need to do this from a specific component, without modifying the existing Joomla components. I need somehow to override the content output and append the necessary elements.
Is this possible?

Comment: For future reference you might want to consider posting to http://joomla.stackexchange.com/ for Joomla questions ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is a good place to start - https://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/Content
If you look at the examples it will show you how to write a plugin that can hook into the content a certain point and manipulate it as you see fit using one of the listed functions.

I would put a conditional statement in the hook to find the parameters that match my component and then output my url/button when the condition is matched.